# Take that! (What is 'that' here?)

Tags: phrase-usage, pronouns

> Take that!

One of dictionaries says : You say 'take that!' when you hit a person or say something while attacking him?

Q: What's 'that' here?

Comment: 'That' is presumably the blow being inflicted on them. (Cambridge Dictionary says 'especially in humorous films or cartoons' - I don't know whether anyone actually says it in real life.

Comment: As per Kate Bunting, 'Take that!' is a cliche' not usually used unless the person saying it is trying to be humorous. If several blows or attacks are made in rapid succession, the verbal statement might be 'Take that! And that and that and that!'

Comment: @KateBunting - as I recall, people said 'Take that!' in _The Dandy_